# Avoid N+1 selects from Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In my project we have hbm.xml file which is fetch="select" for one-to-many for all relation tables.

For ex: 
One school is having many classrooms and one classroom will have many children

so in my hbm file

school.hbm.xml 
<set name="classrooms" **lazy="false" fetch="select"**>

classroom.hbm.xml 
<set name="children" **lazy="false" fetch="select"**>

There is a case where I want to fetch only list of schools which are based on classroom div = 'A'. But because of this mapping hibernate is doing select for classroom as well which I don't want in this case.

Please help me how can I avoid doing unnecessary select with classroom. Is there anyway to override this fetch mode and join only with School and classroom and **not** with children

I tried with multiple options but no luck. 
Really appreciate for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - I believe you cannot override EAGER mappings, neither using find, query nor criteria queries. E.g see [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072568/hibernate-overriding-mappings-eager-in-hql). Overriding LAZY is though easy.

> hbm.xml file which is fetch="select" for one-to-many for all relation tables

...seems like a bad default choice - that's why the opposite is Hibernate's own default choice.

Usually it's a good practice to stay low and lazy in mappings, and use queries when you're eager.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Agree but we have a situation where we need to load some mapping objects eagerly. Now we cannot do change that mapping.